# Not able to get total of dynamically generated fields in html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an application in which I have to add dynamic fields and total of the dynamic fields. 
I'm able to generate dynamic fields with the below code but I'm not able to get the total of all the dynamically generated fields.

**HTML CODE**

```
      <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                    <div>total <lable id='total'></lable></div>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i=1;
            $('#add').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
                $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
            });

            $(".name_list").keyup(function(){
                //alert("sample");
                var sum =0;
                $(".name_list").each(function(){
                    sum += Number($(this).val());
                });
                $("#total").val(sum);
            });
        **//For Delete** 
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){

        var total = $(".total").val();
            var sum = 0;
            $(".name_list").each(function(){
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            });
            var New_total = sum - total; 
            $("#total").text(New_total);

});

        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the fields and buttons are dynamically generated. You have to delegate the events.

```
$("#dynamic_field").on('keyup', '.name_list', function(){
    var sum =0;
    $(".name_list").each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#total").text(sum); //changed val() to text()
});
```

Please go through this for more info [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: indeed Delegate Delegate Delegate

Comment: Happy to help. Remember event delegation next time you deal with dynamic elements.

Comment: Sure.thumbs up.

Comment: since total is the id of the label,  var total = $("#total").text(); and for setting $("#total").text(New_total); And i am afraid you don't have a button with id #delete.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate Delegate Delegate events

```
$("#dynamic_field").on('keyup', '.name_list', function(){
    var sum =0;
    $(".name_list").each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#totalInput").val(sum);
    $("#total").text(sum);
});
```

then create a hidden filed with the a id and name  in the form

```
<div>total 
 <label id='total'></label>
 <input id="totalInput" name="total">
</div>
```

so you can have access to the total in the ajax event and php

Comment: Its not working with  val(sum); but its working well with text(sum);

Comment: so you want the value appended on the screen not send to the php

Comment: then you need both a label and a hidden input see my updated answer

Comment: don't forget the green check if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you trying to check your results? In your PHP which is not posted?

Here's a codepen of your example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMVgYj

and I am looking at this part specifically:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){    
  console.log('here');
    $.ajax({
        url:"name.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $('#add_name')[0].reset();
        }
    });
});
```

I checked my network in inspect tools to see what's sent:

`name[]  {…}
0   a
1   b
2   c`

You could do a `count($_POST['name'])` to see how many items you got back, and foreach through the values...